# how can i add a date with the value of sensor in my serial monitor

Tags: c++, c, date, arduino

I want to display the date on my serial monitor with  the value of sensor

heres the code:

```
int redpin= 13;
int greenled = 7;
int buzzer = 11;
int gasA0 = A0;
// Your threshold value
int sensorThres = 400;
int date = date;


void setup() {
  pinMode(greenled, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gasA0, INPUT); 
  Serial.begin(9600);

}


void loop() {
int analogSensor = analogRead(gasA0);

  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(analogSensor);
  
  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (analogSensor > sensorThres)
  
  {
    digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);//green led stay
    digitalWrite(redpin,HIGH); //turns on led and buzzer
    tone(buzzer,100);
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(redpin,LOW); //turns off led and buzzer
    digitalWrite(greenled,HIGH);//green led stay
    noTone(buzzer);
   
  }
  
delay(400);
}
```

I try to create a device that will detect a gas but I want to display the current date in my serial monitor continuously

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is your question? Is it about displaying the date? Is it about retrieving the date? Do you have a RTC module for your Arduino? Which and how is it connected? Do you have some ESP8266/ESP32 devices with WIFI where you could get time and date via NTP? Please add all relevant details to your question. Please also show your current effort. That code snippet does not contain anything related to a display or to date handling.

Comment: Is this sensor connected to a computer or any device that has the concept of "date" or "time" (e.g. GPS receiver)? If not, then you wont be able to get the value of date unless you inject it somehow from a remote device before sending out the value with the sensor reading. Alternatively, you can use an RTC to get time context (you can find more on RTCs here: https://www.techopedia.com/definition/2273/real-time-clock-rtc).

Comment: i connecting my arduino to excel to display the data from my serial monitor but the only data display in excel is just the value of sensor and time so i want to display the date also how can i do that? i create a real-time monitoring to my gas detector using MQ6 is there any module i need, to do that?

Comment: Where do you get the time? Your code does not contain anything you are talking about. Are you asking how to show current data in Excel or are you asking about Arduino?

Comment: It is rather unclear what you want to achieve at all. Please edit your question to explain how your setup is. How are Arduino, Serial Monitor, Excel connected and where do you want to change something?

Comment: the time value is prepended by the SerialMonitor to every line. if you copy the lines from Serial Monitor to Excel, just add a column with the date in Excel directly

Comment: @Juraj: if Kenchi shows how the values move from SerialMonitor to Excel, there are probably several ways to add the current date and time by Excel. (but that'll be an excel question) Arduino itself does not know anything about timestamps except the millis since reset.

Comment: It seems, the code you show is 100% irelevant for your question. Same as C, C++ or Arduino. Your problem is only communication between 2 programs on a PC. Why don't you show the stuff you are talking about instead?

Answer (score 1):

The time value is prepended by the Arduino Serial Monitor to every line received from Arduino. If you copy the lines from Serial Monitor to Excel, just add a column with the date in Excel directly.
[image]

---

If you want the Arduino to print the timestamp, then you can use the Arduino Time library and some source of time. The source of time can be manual entry, a RTC module or with a networking module you could retrieve time from a time server. See the examples of the Time library